# symfony 3 file upload Accept.php throws InvalidMediaType

Tags: angular, symfony

We have done file upload function, which works when we upload file with chrome plugin postman.

But when we test with angular 2 app, we get error:

[image]

Passing headers like this:

```
POST /groups/b7eedbcc-2c88-11e6-b44b-84e5c9e767ae/uploaded-files HTTP/1.1
Host: [our project domain]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 6418
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: undefined
Origin: http://172.17.2.101:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
Authorization: undefined
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Referer: http://172.17.2.101:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,lt;q=0.6
```

In postman when I upload, I use only 2:

```
Authorization: 123
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Its weird that Authorization is undefined in upper, but if authentication does not pass, the response is

```
{
  "message": "Authentication required"
}
```

so it should not be a problem yet.

What does this error mean? How to solve?

What I have noticed that it does not come to a symfony controller, by trying to use die();

Answer (score 0):

Found out that problem was that Accept header was undefined.

Hardcoded to 'application/json' in symfony system files, and it throwed another error that its not authorized.

Then also hardcoded authorisation key, and file was uploaded.